# Move/rotate tail of speech bubble with the mouse

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a speech bubble and I want to drag the tip of the speech bubble all around the corner of the bubble with the mouse. It should also rotate automatically depending on which side it is on.

My code:

```
<div class="bubble">
        <div class="pointer" id="position4">
        </div>
        <div class="pointerBorder" style="display: none; left: 74px; top: 120px; border-width: 14px 14px 0px; border-color: rgb(127, 127, 127) transparent;">
        </div>
    </div>

CSS:  

.bubble {
    position: relative;
    top: 115px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #fff;
    background-color:red;
    border: #bbb solid 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.pointer {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 200px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-color: red transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
}
.pointerBorder {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 104px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    border-color: blue transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 20px 0;
}
```

the tail that is moving it must be in all direction i mean it should be draggable to all the side of the divs now it is for only one side and it must be on mouse drag..so that i can drag my tail by using mouse where ever i want bt that should be only across the border only..plz some give solution.

Comment: The tail is on the square div. What exactly do you want to do? Are you asking for the js code?

Comment: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: Where do you want to move it to? Please be more specific.

Comment: As i have mentioned above it must be dragged using mouse across the border of the div.it must be on the border only that i can drag across the border.

Comment: Are you Understand.plz give solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want the tail to move along the boarder, then you could do something like this:

```
var direction = "right";
var movementInterval = 1;

setInterval(function() {
    var left = $('.pointer').css('left');
    var leftNumber = parseInt(left, 10);

    if(direction == "right"){
        if(leftNumber > 200){
            direction = "left";
        }
        leftNumber += movementInterval;
    }else{
        if(leftNumber < 15){
            direction = "right";
        }
        leftNumber -= movementInterval;
    }

    $('.pointer').css('left', leftNumber + 'px');
}, 10);
```

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H492a/2/) to see it in action

Comment: Great!!!Thanx for this..but the tail that is moving it must be in all direction i mean it should be draggable to all the side of the divs now it is for only one side and it must be on mouse drag..so that i can drag my tail by using mouse where ever i want bt that should be only across the border only...

Comment: "plz Give Solution": Sorry that's not how StackOverflow works. You might consider reading this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Try it yourself based on my example and ask again if you have specific questions.

Comment: This might help as well: http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx

Comment: drag the tail(.pointer) all side of the div Border.Please give Solution.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is to move the arrow to the top of the square then you need to change your pointer styling to:

```
.pointer {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: -10px;
left: 200px;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
border-color: red transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 15px 15px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/H492a/1/)